# Emulador do Android Studio com processador AMD

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando começar a desenvolver aplicativos para Android, mas infelizmente estou tendo alguns problemas para usar o emulador do Android Studio na hora de testar o aplicativo. Basicamente ao tentar executar recebo o seguinte erro:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>
> CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Pesquisei um pouco e li algumas soluções, entre elas

- Desabilitar o Hyper-V usando d"ism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V"
- Desabilitar virtualização assistida por hardware no Avast
- Depois de fazer as duas coisas tentar instalar o Intel HAXM

E tudo isso deu errado. Sempre que tento instalar o Intel HAXM recebo um erro

> This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

Pesquisando mais li que não tem como instalar esse Intel HAXM usando processador AMD. É realmente esse o caso? Não tem nenhuma solução para conseguir usar o emulador usando um processador AMD?

Comment: Processadores da AMD não implementam as instruções VT-x da Intel, da mesma forma que a Intel não implementa as instruções AMD-V da AMD. Estas instruções são fundamentais para virtualização. No caso, o Android suporta virtualização apenas através das instruções VT-x, e portanto pode ser virtualizado apenas  em processadores Intel. Não é possível utilizar uma imagem x86 em processador AMD (mesmo emulando). A Intel criou isto pois o port x86 do Android é feito por ela, e foi a forma que encontrou de proteger o investimento: dependendo de um conjunto de instruções que o concorrente não implementa.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível usar aceleração de hardware para o emulador com processadores AMD no Windows e Mac se não estou enganado, processadores AMD só são suportados no Linux segundo a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

Neste caso você deve usar uma imagem do emulador que não seja para processadores x86, mas a execução deve ser bem lenta. O ideal ainda acho que seria você usar diretamente um aparelho com Android para debugar, acho que mais rápido e prático do que usar emuladores.

Answer (score 0):

se voce precisa debugar a sua aplicação, tem o emulador BlueStacks, eu utilizo e acho rápido para depuração de apps, posso acessar a base de dados diretamente, enfim...tenta dar uma olhada, talvez te ajude.
http://www.bluestacks.com/download.html
pra acessar o modo depuração, as vezes tem que ir no cmd e digitar "adb connect 127.0.0.1", após isso ele aparece no Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Eu estou tendo o mesmo problema e parece que não há mesmo solução para isso.

O que está funcionando para mim é usar o emulador Android "Andy", que eu até já tinha instalado no PC por outros motivos, então ficou bem prático.

Se já estiver com o Andy aberto, quando clicar em run 'app' vai aparecer uma janela onde o emulador vai aparecer como se fosse um dispositivo real conectado e vai simular certinho ali.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu processador é AMD realmente não tem como usar a tecnologia HAXM. Mas Tem como usar o emulador do android studio. Basta que você abra o AVD Manager > Creat virtual device (escolha a configuração desejada, ou crie uma) > next > Ecolha a ABI que começa com "amr" (Tem duas, pode escolher qualquer uma delas, eu uso a de TARGT - Google APIs). Escolha um nome pra ele. Na hora que você executar vai aparecer as opções de emulador disponíveis, aí é só escolher o que você criou. Lembrando que se tiver erro no código do projeto que está aberto ou erros de configuração, o emulador não vai abrir. A diferença em não poder usar HAXM é que o emulador vai ficar bem lento. De toda forma a melhor opção é testar suas aplicações em um dispositivo real, é o mais rápido.